Show data using PrimeNG DataView?
I'm developing a personal project using Angular17 and I wanted to show the items in my database using a PrimeNG component, DataView. So far so good, I made the imports in app.module and the request to the service to bring the data. The issue is that the data is not being shown in the DataView but the pagination works (it shows the 3 pages of data (11 items)). I talked to the copilot and it suggested that I would use Table instead of DataView. It worked with the table, but not with the DataView. Does anyone have any idea?
Some contents is typed in Portuguese - BR because it's my native language and it's a personal project.
edit-client.HTML
 <div class="card"> 
    <div class="content">
      <p-dataView #dv [value]="dados" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="list" let-cliente>
          <div>{{cliente.nomeCliente}}</div>
          <div class="fila-item" (click)="abrirModalEditarCliente(cliente)"></div>
        </ng-template>
      </p-dataView>
    </div>    
  </div> 

edit-client.component.ts
export class EditClientComponent implements OnInit {
  dados: Fila[] = [];

  constructor(private filaService: FilaService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDataFromService();
  }

  getDataFromService() {
    this.filaService.getDataFromDatabase().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dados = data;
      console.log(this.dados)
    });
  }

The console.log(this.dados) shows entire data in my console (11 itens).
Fila.ts
export interface Fila {
    id: number;
    nomeCliente: string;
  }
  

A funny question is that Table works fine and shows the content perfectly. But I want to use DataView.
edit-client.HTML (table)
  <p-table [value]="dados" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Nome do Cliente</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cliente>
      <tr (click)="abrirModalEditarCliente(cliente)">
        <td>{{cliente.nomeCliente}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>

I've tried to use *ngFor, it shows the data, but showed all data at once. I want to show 5 per page.

From what I see from the code snippet the issue is that you are not using *ngFor.  Here is what it should look like
<p-dataView #dv [value]="dados" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">
  <ng-template let-collection pTemplate="list">
    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let item of collection;">{{item.name}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataView>

I assume that you tried to iterate inside the ng-template over the dados not over the date incoming from the let-cliente, so that is why the pagination didn't work for you.
If we check primeNg source, we can find the following thing
      <div class="p-dataview-content">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: paginator ? (filteredValue || value | slice : (lazy ? 0 : first) : (lazy ? 0 : first) + rows) : filteredValue || value }"></ng-container>

                <div *ngIf="isEmpty() && !loading">
                    <div class="p-dataview-emptymessage">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="!emptyMessageTemplate; else empty">
                            {{ emptyMessageLabel }}
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container #empty *ngTemplateOutlet="emptyMessageTemplate"></ng-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

Where we can see that the itemTemplate is getting the full collection, so inside of it we should iterate over every single item. If you are interested in checking the source of the lib you can find it here : prmieNG github

Ok! I did this way <p-dataView #dv [value]="dados" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true">         <ng-template let-dados pTemplate="list">           <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let cliente of dados;">{{cliente.nomeCliente}}</div>         </ng-template>
WORKS!!!
